# Python and computer sleeping

Tags: python, loops

I'm using time.sleep() on a crypto price checking app I made. But i can only get it to run for a couple hours then the device I run it on will sleep. How do you get something to just run your script for hours/days/weeks?

I've ran this program on my computer, a raspberry pi, and an old android phone and the best I can get is the phone will run the program from 9pm to 5am on a good day.

I've tried turning off all sleep timers and all and I'd really rather not keep my PC on constantly but I'd love some help finding a solution none the less.

Comment: This isn't a Python problem; it's an OS-configuration problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a Windows machine, you can go to Task Scheduler and create running your script as a task at a particular time.

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/wake-up-computer-from-sleep-windows